# Enter variable name in textbox and get corresponding value

Tags: javascript, variables, updates

I have created 3 variables a,b,c. I have assigned values to a and b and have also made a textbox. What I want to do is enter the name of a the variable in the textbox and click the button, then the textbox should should display the value assigned to that variable. It maybe very simple but I do not know what I did wrong.

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vh8AB/1/)**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function display(){
                var a = 2;
                var b = 3;
                var c = document.getElementById("b1").value;       
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=c;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" id="b1">
        <button type="button" onclick="display()">Display</button>
        <p id="demo">Update Value.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: Example: If i enter a and click the button ..then it should display 2

Comment: Mmm no it shouldn't, not with that code, it should display : a, you need to have a `switch` statement or something to say that you want to replace the value of the field with the value of one of your variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest choice would be to assign your variables to a object, like this:

```
var vars;

function display() {
    var value = document.getElementById("b1").value;
    vars = {
        a: 2,
        b: 3,
        c: value
    }
    if (vars.hasOwnProperty(value)) { // If the entered value is a variable name
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vars[value]; // Display the variable
    } else { // Otherwise
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value; // display the value
    }
}
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BKxWT/2/)**

The `if/else` can be replaced with this, to make it a little shorter:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vars.hasOwnProperty(value) // If
                                                ? vars[value]          // Then
                                                : vars.c;              // Else
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function display(){
                var a = 2;
                var b = 3;
                var c = document.getElementById("b1").value;
                if(c==a){
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML='a';
                }
                if(c==b){
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML='b';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="b1">
        <button type="button" onclick="display()">Display</button>
        <p id="demo">Update value.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vh8AB/1/)

Comment: While this works, it's not very flexible.
When a variable is added, you'd have to add a `if` statement also. Also, use `if/else`'s, or a switch / case statement, otherwise all those `if` statements will be evaluated while only one can ever be `true`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the eval() method (Which, do a quick google search, it is not recommended).

```
    <script>
        function display(){
            var a = 2;
            var b = 3;
            var c = document.getElementById("b1").value;       
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=(eval(c));
            // if user enters b in the input field, then the html in demo will be 3
            // if user enters a in the input field, then the html in demo will be 2
        }
    </script>
```

Again, not recommended!

Comment: There are other ways to do this. Directly using `eval` on user input is just asking for someone to mess with your code.

Comment: Downvote is unnecessary since it is the answer that the op was looking for. I made 2 remarks for him to research eval before using it.

Comment: If an OP is looking for something that can be done in more than one way, it's usually a good idea to suggest a tweak in the OP's code if that means removing huge security issues.

`eval` is more often than not reason enough for a downvote, since there are often alternatives.

Also, users tend to copy code without doing further research. At the very least, explain why `eval` is evil, instead of suggesting to use it, and telling a OP to look for a reason he shouldn't.

Comment: It's a good thing for developers to know the best and worst practices. We all know that eval is bad, except people asking questions like this. Now OP knows too.

Comment: I'll just **[link to an article explaining why eval's evil, here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)**. Saves users from searching ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare variables directly in you `script`-element they are created as properties of the `window`-object and can be accessed as such. Thus just update your script like the following to show the contents of the variables:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var a = 2, b = 3;
            function display() {
                var strVarName = document.getElementById('b1').value;
                if(window.hasOwnProperty(strVarName)) {
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = window[strVarName];
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Variable ' + strVarName + ' does not exist.'
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="b1">
        <button type="button" onclick="display()">Display</button>
        <p id="demo">Update Value.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This won't work if you declare the variables inside the display function, but this doesn't seem like a thing you would do if this code were to be used in a system to anything beside this one simple function.